Selenium Devtools NoSuchMethodError
I am trying to start a new DevToolsSession with:
 WebDriverManager.chromedriver().driverVersion("121.0.6167.184").setup();
 ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
 devTools.createSession();

and I get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.function.Function org.openqa.selenium.devtools.ConverterFunctions.map(java.lang.String, java.util.function.Function)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v121.target.Target.getTargets(Target.java:153)
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v121.v121Target.getTargets(v121Target.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools.findTarget(DevTools.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools.createSession(DevTools.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools.createSession(DevTools.java:117)

I am thinking that must be a dependency error, but I don't know what I am missing.
My pom.xml looks like this:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v121</artifactId>
    <version>4.19.1</version>
</dependency>

I am using Chrome version 121.0.6157.0
And Chromedriver version  121.0.6167.184
My imports:
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

Edit: I added my initialization of the ChromeDriver and my imports.
It still doesn't work.

driver.getDevTools() is not an available method for me... why do you think this is supposed to work? Add your imports to your question as well.

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted.

you might check Selenium's own test methods for CDP API here... not sure what Java version they use: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk/examples/java/src/test/java/dev/selenium/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/CdpApiTest.java

If you try/catch that cast to HasDevTools it might tell you something.... devTools = ((HasDevTools) driver).getDevTools();  I know in the past either remote or local didn't have it.

You didn't include your declaration of driver in your code but I'm guessing you declared it like
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

The problem is that WebDriver does not support the .getDevTools() method. Only ChromeDriver does. Change your declaration to the following and it works with no errors for me.
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();


Also, you no longer need to use an external DriverManager. As of v4.6, Selenium now contains SeleniumManager which automatically downloads and configures the appropriate drivers.

Unfortunately that doesn't fix the error

The issue is because of the mismatching version of dependencies.

Selenium-java
selenium-devtools-v125 ( vXVersion)

For the above dependencies the version should match, if its mismatching then you'll face above errors
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.23.0</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v127</artifactId>
            <version>4.23.0</version>
        </dependency>

